# Regex Error cannot compile Match.Count

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I am writing a VBA script to use as an outlook macro. The goal is to automatically sort emails into folders, based on case numbers in the subject line.

First I tried using the "string like" function, which was ok to select the right emails, but I need more flexibility, so am trying to use regex. 
Here is my code so far. I have gotten stuck on

```
   If objMatch.Count > 0 Then
```

Attempts to compile results in error: "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

I have scoured the web to see what I'm doing wrong, but I think match.count should be valid. I'm not experienced in VB, so I would appreciate any specific tips.

Full code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FoldalotMacro()
Dim fdr As String
Dim CaseFolders As Folder

Dim strEmail As String
Dim RegEx As RegExp
Dim objMatch As Match
Dim objMatches As MatchCollection
Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RegEx
    .Pattern = ".*(68\d{7})(.{0,20}).*"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = False
End With

Dim Sel, Item

  ' ** Source: Items to be processed
  Set Sel = Outlook.Session.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("caseinbox").Items
  ' ** Target folder
  Set CaseFolders = Outlook.Session.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("casetest")

  For Each Item In Sel
   Set objMatch = RegEx.Execute(Item.Subject)
   ' ** Run Regex against item subject
   If objMatch.Count > 0 Then
   ' ** folder title is the extracted case number
        Set fdr = objMatch.Item(0).SubMatches(0)
        ' ** create the folder if it does not exist
        If CaseFolders.Folders(fdr) Is Nothing Then CaseFolders.Folders.Add fdr
        End If
        Item.Move CaseFolders.Folders(fdr)
    Else
    ' ** alert if no action
        Debug.Print "no match found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit: I have got several steps further. New code:

```
    ' process manually
Option Explicit
Sub FoldalotMacro()
Dim fdr As String
Dim CaseFolders As Outlook.Folder
Dim Counter As Long
Dim strEmail As String
Dim Sel2 As Outlook.Folder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Sel

Dim RegEx As RegExp
Dim objMatch As Match
Dim objMatches As MatchCollection
Dim submatches As submatches
Set RegEx = New RegExp
With RegEx
    .Pattern = ".*(6\d{8})(.{0,20}).*"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = False
End With

  '  Source: Items to be processed
Set Sel2 = Outlook.Session.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("caseinbox")
Set Sel = Sel2.Items
  '  Target folder
  Set CaseFolders = Outlook.Session.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("casetest")

    For Each Item In Sel
        Set objMatches = RegEx.Execute(Item.Subject)
         '  Run Regex against item subject
        If objMatches.Count > 0 Then
            fdr = objMatches.Item(0)
            If CaseFolders.Folders(fdr) Is Nothing Then CaseFolders.Folders.Add fdr
            Item.Move CaseFolders.Folders(fdr)
        Else
            MsgBox "No match found:  " & Item.Subject
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Getting stuck on this part:

```
    fdr = objMatches.Item(0)
    If CaseFolders.Folders(fdr) Is Nothing Then CaseFolders.Folders.Add fdr
```

I defined fdr as String to get this to work, but to search for the folder name it needs an object. What should I define for fdr?

Comment: That's because a `Match` object apparently doesn't expose a `Count` member - the `Count` would be on the `MatchCollection` object. Did you look at its members in the *Object Browser* (F2)? Also, since you've referenced the library, then why are you late-binding the `RegEx` object creation instead of just `New`ing it up?

Comment: **`Dim objMatch As Variant`** should fix it??? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Dim RegEx As RegExp
> Dim objMatch As Match
> Dim objMatches As MatchCollection
> ```

If that code compiles, then you obviously have a reference to the regular expressions library; [Macro Man's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42582909/1188513) is correct, you have no reason whatsoever to use `CreateObject` to create an instance of a class you can readily `New` up.

All referenced libraries can be browsed using the *object browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd> in the VBE):

[image: Members of 'Match']

The `Match` class doesn't have a `Count` member, so when you typed this (assuming you *typed* it):

> ```
> If objMatch.Count > 0 Then
> ```

You weren't paying attention to what *IntelliSense* was telling you:

[image: IntelliSense listing members of Match in a dropdown]

---

The `Execute` method doesn't return a `Match` object. Of course it's not obvious, because the `Execute` method returns an `Object`, which could be just about anything, right? With `TypeName` you can find out the truth:

```
Sub DoSomething()

    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\w"
        Dim result As Object
        Set result = .Execute("foo bar")
        Debug.Print TypeName(result)
    End With

End Sub
```

Prints `IMatchCollection2` - an interface that's obviously implemented by the `MatchCollection` type: `Execute` therefore returns a *match collection* object.

[image: IMatchCollection hidden interface]

So instead of this:

> ```
> Set objMatch = RegEx.Execute(Item.Subject)
> ```

Do this:

```
Set objMatches = RegEx.Execute(Item.Subject)
```

And then iterate the `Match` objects in that collection.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have successfully compiled the code now, and have got as far as popping up a message for each match:

`  For Each Item In Sel 
   Set objMatches = RegEx.Execute(Item.Subject)
        For Counter = 0 To objMatches.Count - 1
            MsgBox objMatches(Counter)
        Next `

However, I don't really understand what the Counter is doing. Got the example from https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1336/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html.
And I would still like to extract the submatch from my regex (just the #)

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
If objMatch.Length > 0 Then
```

[(see here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)

also, you appear to have a reference set to the VBScript RegExp library, but then you use late binding to create your RegEx object:

```
Dim RegEx As RegExp '// Early bound
Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") '// Late bound
```

instead just do:

```
Dim RegEx As RegExp
Set RegEx = New RegExp
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution:
(I have added some comments to hopefully be helpful to the next person)

```
Option Explicit
Private Function FolderExists(Inbox As MAPIFolder, FolderName As String)
    Dim Sub_Folder As MAPIFolder

    On Error GoTo Exit_Err
    Set Sub_Folder = Inbox.Folders(FolderName)

    FolderExists = True
        Exit Function

Exit_Err:
    FolderExists = False

End Function

Sub FoldalotMacro()
Dim fdr As String
Dim CaseFolders As Outlook.Folder
Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Sel2 As Outlook.Folder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Sel

Dim RegEx As RegExp
Dim objMatch As Match
Dim objMatches As MatchCollection
Dim submatches As submatches
Set RegEx = New RegExp
With RegEx
' Change this regex pattern to suit your needs. 
    .Pattern = ".*(6\d{8})(.{0,20}).*"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = False
End With


  '  Source: Items to be processed
Set Sel2 = Outlook.Session.Folders("Account Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("SourceFolderName")
Set Sel = Sel2.Items
  '  Target folder
  Set CaseFolders = Outlook.Session.Folders("Account Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("DestinationRootFolder")
    For Each Item In Sel
        Set objMatches = RegEx.Execute(Item.subject)
         '  Run Regex against item subject. is there a match?
        If objMatches.Count > 0 Then
            ' Folder name will be the extracted number
            fdr = objMatches.Item(0).submatches(0)
            ' Check if folder already exists
            If FolderExists(CaseFolders, fdr) = True Then
                Set SubFolder = CaseFolders.Folders(fdr)
            Else
                ' Create the folder if it does not exist
                Set SubFolder = CaseFolders.Folders.Add(fdr)
            End If
            Item.Move SubFolder
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I still have a small issue: When running the macro it should process all the items in the source folder. But it only processes 4-7 of them, then stops. If I run again, it moves a few more, and so on. I debugged and found that everything is selected properly, but "Item.move" still only moves a random few in the list.
Nonetheless my initial question was already answered, thanks everyone :)

Comment: v1 cool - Post a new question and we will try to help you out